# Coroutines for access Room inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am developing a Chat Application. For the chatRoomActivity i have a RecyclerView and i give the Adapter a list of Messages and other stuff. There is a senario where the MessageBody is not a text but it is an ID so that i can query my Database and find the description of a particular object byId. I was thinking about start a Coroutine with IO Dispatcher and then withContext(Main) to get the result an update the holder field. 
Do you think thats a good approach....?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with doing it like that. But make sure to cancel the coroutine when the holder is no longer for that particular message.